# Sage: Why is z.conjugate().simplify() = z?

Tags: python, sage

> ```
> sage: var("z", domain="complex")
>  z
>  sage: z.conjugate()
>  conjugate(z)
>  sage: z.conjugate().simplify()
>  z
> ```

This seems obviously wrong. Is there any specific reason for this behavior, and how can I turn it off?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: `z.conjugate().simplify()` gives me `conjugate(z)` as expected. Are you sure you didn't do `z = z.conjugate()`? or something like that?

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks for the feedback! I did exactly the things I quoted. However, my version of sage (6.2, 2014-05-06) might be a little old, and I'll see if the bug persists.

Comment: Yes, I think that finally got fixed...